# ASP.NET MVC - Controller level attributes (filters) - Have them execute after action level attributes?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, filter, attributes

Is there a way to have controller level filters execute after the action level filters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try specifying the scope as global and changing the Order parameter. Are these filters you have control over?

Check out:
http://rajsoftware.wordpress.com/2011/05/14/mvc3-filter-ordering/

Comment: I don't have control over the action level attributes. I am implementing the *controller level* attribute. Am I correct in understanding the Order property overrides scope? i.e. *controller level* order of 2 runs after *action level* order of 1?